# Python 2.7 TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_getitem_'

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I'm pretty new to coding and have been trying some things out.  I am getting this error when I run a python script I have.  I have read that this error is because something is returning "None" but I'm having trouble figuring out what is causing it (still trying to learn all of this).

The purpose of the script is pulling thumbnails from videos and searching the internet for other instances of the same thing.  After running my python script, it returns a result of:

```
    [*] Retrieving video ID: VIDEOID
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "VidSearch.py", line 40, in <module>
    thumbnails = video_data['items'][0]['snippet']['thumbnails']
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no atribute '_getitem_'
```

The following is the script I am running (Youtube Key removed):

```
import argparse
import requests
import json

from pytineye import TinEyeAPIRequest

tineye = TinEyeAPIRequest('http://api.tineye.com/rest/','PUBLICKEY','PRIVATEKEY')

youtube_key = "VIDEOID"

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v","--videoID",    required=True,help="The videoID of the YouTube video. For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEOID")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

video_id    = args['videoID']

#
# Retrieve the video details based on videoID
#
def youtube_video_details(video_id):

    api_url  = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CrecordingDetails&"
    api_url += "id=%s&" % video_id
    api_url += "key=%s" % youtube_key

    response = requests.get(api_url)

    if response.status_code == 200:

        results = json.loads(response.content)

        return results

    return None


print "[*] Retrieving video ID: %s" % video_id
video_data = youtube_video_details(video_id)

thumbnails = video_data['items'][0]['snippet']['thumbnails']

print "[*] Thumbnails retrieved. Now submitting to TinEye."

url_list = []

# add the thumbnails from the API to the list
for thumbnail in thumbnails:

    url_list.append(thumbnails[thumbnail]['url'])


# build the manual URLS
for count in range(4):

    url = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/%s/%d.jpg" % (video_id,count)

    url_list.append(url)


results = []

# now walk over the list of URLs and search TinEye
for url in url_list:

    print "[*] Searching TinEye for: %s" % url

    try:
        result = tineye.search_url(url)
    except:
        pass

    if result.total_results:
        results.extend(result.matches)

result_urls = []
dates       = {}

for match in results:

    for link in match.backlinks:

        if link.url not in result_urls:

            result_urls.append(link.url)
            dates[link.crawl_date] = link.url

print            
print "[*] Discovered %d unique URLs with image matches." % len(result_urls)

for url in result_urls:

    print url


oldest_date = sorted(dates.keys())

print
print "[*] Oldest match was crawled on %s at %s" % (str(oldest_date[0]),dates[oldest_date[0]])
```

I know it's probably something simple but I can't seem to figure it out for the life of me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error is when trying to index `video_data`, `video_data` is obtained from `youtube_video_details`. See, what does `youtube_video_details` return if `status_code != 200`?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Tried that and got a KeyError. Will look more into it when I get off work.

Answer (score 0):

In your `youtube_video_details` method. the response.status_code maybe is not `200`, so the method return the `None`

So you can do like this:

```
video_data = youtubo_video_details(video_id)

if not video_data:        

    thumbnails = video_data['items'][0]['snippet']['thumbnails']
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try it when I get off work.